# DP - Finding the maximum sum of an array with a specific set of rules

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is regarding a specific DP question/problem that I received a while ago when I was being interviewed for a SE internship program. I could not figure out a proper solution for it then and it has been bugging me since. The silver lining is that I realized that I needed to work on my DP techniques.

So, the question goes like this:-

Given an array `n` (i.e. `[1, 5, 0]` and a set of nodes with a size of `n + 1` (in this case, there would be `4` nodes), these nodes need be arranged in such a way in order to find the maximum value that can be extracted from this arrangement of nodes. The given criteria is as follows:-

- Each position/index in the array represents how many of the other nodes that the current node can be connected to; i.e. The first index would mean that a node is connected to one other node, the second would mean that a node is connected to two other nodes and so on and so forth.
- Each value in the array represents how much gain you can extract should a node be connected to one, two, three, ..., (n - 1) other nodes. So, if a node is connected to one other node, the value extracted (in this case) would be 1 (according to the above array).
- The arrangement of these nodes cannot be circular. i.e. `X1 -- X2 -- X3 -- X4` is acceptable.

I think a few examples would help in getting a better idea of the problem domain:-

Input: `[1, 5, 0]` | Expected output: `12` | Expected arrangement of nodes: `X -- X -- X -- X`

Explanation:- There are 4 nodes in total, the input indicates that a node will yield 1 unit of value/gain if it’s connected with exactly one other node, 5 units if it’s directly connected with 2 other nodes and no value/gain at all if it’s directly connected with 3 other nodes. In the optimal setting (shown above), the first and last nodes yield 1 unit each (each of them is connected to one other node) whereas the two nodes in the middle of the sequence yields 5 units of nodes each. The maximum amount of collectible value/gain is thus 1+5+5+1 = 12.

Input `[0, 0, 0, 0, 50]` | Expected output: `50` | Expected arrangement of nodes: *Think of a STAR shape with the `(n+1)`th node in the middle since the gain is 50 if a node is connected to 5 other nodes.

Input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` | Expected output: `12`

Input `[3, 9, 6, 15, 9, 21, 15]` | Expected output: `60`

Feel free to drop questions if you don't really understand the given problem/the examples given and I'll try my best to clarify them.

As I have said, I am in the midst of improving myself with DP-specific problems. So, I don't expect a full solution to be given here. I am only asking for hints/clues/a starting point that I can work on/with. An algorithm to review on would be sufficient too!

Basically, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is, in fact, similar to the problem of generating all the distinct non-isomorphic trees on `n` vertices and then finding the maximum value that can be extracted from the arrangement of nodes.

The number of non-isomorphic trees of order `n` are **1**, **1**, **1**, **2**, **3**, **6**, **11**, **23**, **47**, **106**, **235**, **551**, **1301**, **3159**,... (OEIS A000055) which has a generating function but no known closed formula.

[image: The trees with up to six nodes]

This can be represented by the following listing, in terms of the [degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) sequences.

For example, for `n = 6`:

[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]

[1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1]

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]

[1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1]

However, in our case, both `[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]` and `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]` represent `1(3), 2(2), 3(1)` (one node with three vertices + two nodes with two vertices + three nodes with one vertex). So we can discard all the repeated items and generate the following unordered sequences in reverse lexicographic order:

[5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

[4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]

[2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]

[2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]

**We can say:**

1. In a connected tree with `n` vertices (like above trees), every vertex
   has a [degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) of at least 1 and at most `n-1`.
2. The size `S` of degree sequences of a tree is the same as the number of vertices (it’s obvious!).
3. The sum of the [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) of all the vertices: `C= 2(n-1)` (e.g. for n=6, C = 10).

Problem: For `n` nodes, we have `n-1` types of nodes, where the `ith` item type has a degree `di` and a value `vi`. We are trying to fill a degree sequence `D` with total capacity `C` and size `S` with a selection of items of maximum value. We can add multiple items of the same type to `D`.
This is a similar problem to the `Integer Knapsack Problem` (Duplicate Items Permitted) with some restrictions: the overall weight **must** be equal to `C` and the number of items **must** be equal to `S`.

**Example:** `n = 4`

We have `3` types of node (degrees): `[1, 2, 3]` with given values: `[1, 5, 0]`
The size of the sequence (knapsack) is: `4` and it's capacity = `6`

**DP Solution**:

```
Let us initialize a 3-d array arr[i][j][k] to “unknown” for all i,j,k.
Value(n,C,S)
{
    if (S == 0) return 0; //No more Space
    else if (S > C || S * n < C) return INT_MIN; //impossible to fill!

    if (n == 0) return 0; //No more item

    if (arr[n][C][S] != unknown) return arr[n][C][S];

    if (n > C) result = Value(n-1,C,S); // can’t use nth item
    else if(n == C && S > 1) result = Value(n-1,C,S); // can't use it, if we do, we won't have enough capacity to fill the spaces
    else 
    {
        for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
            q = max{q, P[i] + Value(i, C - i, S - 1)} // P[i] = value of a node with a degree of i

        result = max{q, Value(n - 1, C, S)};
    }
    arr[n][C][S] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi! First off, thanks for the help. I've got a few questions as I still don't fully understand the concept. Could you explain what you meant when you said "However, since we only need the combinations, [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1] is the same as [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]. Now we can discard the repeated items and generate the following combinations"?

Also, if it is not too much to ask, could you explain your code as well? It might be that I still haven't grasped everything yet for me to understand the implementation code.
I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi @cottonman, I edited my answer and the code, take a look at them and if it's not clear, let me know. However, note that the number of partitions p(n) grows exponentially, so anything you do to generate all partitions will necessarily have to take exponential time.

Comment: Hi Rad. Sorry for the late reply. I'll attempt to process it all and get back to you if I have any further queries. Thanks, again! :)

Comment: That's great! I'll take a look at it and get back to you if I have any queries about it. :D